# IEEE code database

Tags: standards, communication, snomed-ct

As SNOMED and LOINC, I read that there is another universal standard for identifying medical terms called IEEE (whose database would also include fitness/diet/environmental data which I would particularly need for the project I am working on).
My problem is that I have been searching for the codes online but I couldn't find any. Does anybody know if you need to pay to access the code database?

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about IEEE as a coding system for medical information-exchange. If I have never heard of it, I have 17 years of experience in healthcare ICT, then it probably is not very well known and therefore fails in the context of interoperability.

Also, IEEE would not be a smart name for a coding system because it conflicts with IEEE as technology standard organization (https://www.ieee.org/index.html)